Unable to keep email messages in same thread Python smtplib
i am automating my gmail messages, User creates account and an automated response created from gpt and is send to the user email and then the user replies to which again response generated from gpt is send to user and it continues, the problem is the conversation is not remaining in a same thread, it create new thread , whenever the user replies.
Admin Automated Email :
def process_emails():
    accounts = account_repo.get_pending_sending_accounts()
    print(f'Found sending accounts with remaining limit today.')

    for account in accounts:
        last_sent_time = account['LastSentTime']
        if last_sent_time is not None:
            next_sending_time = last_sent_time + timedelta(minutes=account['MinimumSendingDelay'])

            print('Last Sent Time:    ', last_sent_time)
            print('Next Sending Time: ', next_sending_time)
            print('Now:               ', datetime.now())

            if next_sending_time > datetime.now():
                print('It\'s not good time, try again later.\n')
                continue

        subject = generate_email_subject()
        print('Subject: ', subject)

        content = generate_email('new', {account['FirstName']}, settings.SENDER_NAME, subject, None)
        content = json.loads(content)

        send_email(account['Email'], content['subject'], content['body'], settings.EMAIL_IDENTIFIER)


Email Helper:
def send_email(recipient, subject, content, unique_identifier, message_id=None, references=None,in_reply_to=None,user=None):
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message['From'] = f"{settings.SENDER_NAME} <{settings.SENT_FROM}>"
    message['To'] = recipient
    message['Subject'] = subject
    message['Reply-To'] = settings.REPLY_TO
    message['X-Unique-Identifier'] = unique_identifier  # Custom header to track the email

    if message_id is None:
        # Generate a new Message-ID for the initial email
        message_id = email.utils.make_msgid(domain="taylorbrokerservices.com")
        message['Message-ID'] = message_id
    else:
        # For replies, set the Message-ID and threading headers
        new_message_id = email.utils.make_msgid(domain="taylorbrokerservices.com")
        message['Message-ID'] = new_message_id
        message['In-Reply-To'] = message_id
        message['References'] = message_id if not references else references

    message.attach(MIMEText(content, 'plain'))

User Reply:
def process_unread_emails(mail):
    response, _ = mail.select(settings.IMAP_INBOX_NAME)
    if response != 'OK':
        raise Exception(f"Failed to select '{settings.IMAP_INBOX_NAME}'")

    _, data = mail.search(None, 'UNSEEN')

    unread_messages = data[0].split()

    protected_emails = settings.PROTECTED_EMAILS.split(',')

    for msg_num in unread_messages:
        _, msg_data = mail.fetch(msg_num, '(RFC822)')

        for response_part in msg_data:
            if not isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                continue

            msg = email.message_from_bytes(response_part[1])
           
            msg_receive_time = datetime.strptime(msg['date'], '%a, %d %b %Y  %H:%M:%S %z')
            msg_receive_time = msg_receive_time.replace(tzinfo=None)
            random_number = random.randint(20, 60)

            reply_time = msg_receive_time + timedelta(minutes=random_number)
            print('Reply Time: ', reply_time)
            print('Now       : ', datetime.now())

            message_id = msg['Message-ID']
            existing_references = msg['References'] if 'References' in msg else ''
            references = f"{existing_references} {message_id}".strip()
            print('Message-ID of User: ', message_id)

            sender = email.utils.parseaddr(msg.get('from'))[1]
            subject = msg.get('subject')

            if not any(pe in sender for pe in protected_emails):
                continue

            payloads = msg.get_payload()
            if len(payloads) == 0:
                continue

            body = payloads[-1].get_payload()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')
            content = generate_email('reply', sender, settings.SENDER_NAME, subject, soup.text)
            content = json.loads(content)

            try:
                send_email(sender, content['subject'], content['body'], settings.EMAIL_IDENTIFIER, message_id, references, in_reply_to=message_id)

